# Not going to the redirected view

Tags: php, laravel, vue-component

I have a store function as follows for the product edit,

```
public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required',
                'category_id' => 'required'
            ]);
    
            if (!empty($request->product_id)) {
                $product = StoreProduct::findOrFail($request->product_id);
                $product->update($request->except('_token'));
                session()->flash('flash_message', 'The product has been updated!');
                return redirect()->route('product.index');
            }
    }
```

It is call by Vue component's method as follows,

```
methods: {
    saveProduct: function () {
        let data = {
            'name' : this.translate.name,
            'category_id' : this.product.id,
            'product_id' : this.translate.product_id,
        }
       axios.post('/store-product', data);
    }
}
```

all the functionalities working fine.but is is not going to the view that redirected by this route (product.index) and remain the edit page. is there any issue with the redirecting part?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue as follows,

```
axios.post('/store-product', data).then(function(response){

  //redirect logic
  if (response.data.status) {
    window.location.href = '/products';
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how axios requests work. If you used a regular form your redirect would work; however since this is a javascript request, axios is not honoring that redirect. See this [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/932). The easiest solution would be to return the route to redirect:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, [
       'name' => 'required',
       'category_id' => 'required'
   ]);
    
   if (!empty($request->product_id)) {
       $product = StoreProduct::findOrFail($request->product_id);
       $product->update($request->except('_token'));
       session()->flash('flash_message', 'The product has been updated!');
       return response(['redirect' => route('product.index')];
   }
}
```

and then in your axios request (this is untested, parsing the response might be slightly off):

```js
axios.post('/store-product', data).then(function(response){
  const response = JSON.parse(response.data.response);

  //redirect logic
  if (response.redirect) {
    window.location.href = response.redirect;
  }
})
```

Comment: It is giving following error -> "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". so, I have used "window.location.href" and it works for me.thank you for your time